# HTML syntax unknown to display a javascript binary string containing a jpeg image

Tags: javascript, image, binary

I can't get through this problem though it must be only a very small syntax problem, as you will see: In fact, I'm searching for just a little piece of syntax, unless what I intend to do would be impossible (But I can see no reason why it should be impossible...).

I have written a function to encode an image into Base64 on server side, because I want to store numerous images into an array:

So, with Base64 I can download images as ordinary strings that I can organize in an array, then put them into an  object just when I have chosen the right image and the right moment, without having to refer to the server again, so that the user doesn't have to wait.

Then I do something like this:

- First phase:

  function download64(imageUrl) //->string
  { // ask the server to send the 'imageUrl' as a base64 string
    var tx = DoTheJob(); // ...connect through ajax and download the image converted in base64 as a string in var 'tx'
    return tx
  }

At this stage, I'm holding the image in the 'tx' Base64-string on client side.
Somewhat later I want to display my image in the div called "cadre", so I do the following:

- Second phase:
  I just have to call the "display64" function to set my image into the "cadre" div-object on the screen:

  display64("cadre",tx);

using this function:

```
function display64(destinationDiv,imgText64)    //->void
{  // display 'imgText64'   into destinationDiv
  var oImg = "<img alt='' src='data:image/jpg;base64," + imgText64 + "'>";
  var x = document.getElementById(destinationDiv);
  x.innerHTML = oImg;       
}
```

Now the image is displayed. Unfortunately, this works well only with Firefox, because Internet Explorer 8 can't read Base64 images above 32Kb! And in my entreprise, we use IE 8 only!

Then I dropped my base64 encoder and decided to fetch the image as a binary string, which I could manage though I initially had a problem with nul character.

Now, I'm here with my binary string containing the exact copy of the source JPG file (including zeros that I have encoded on server side then restored on client side). So, what I need now is the simple function 'displayBin', but I can't find the syntax on the web:

```
function displayBin(destinationDiv,imgTextBin) //->void
{  // display 'imgTextBin' into destinationDiv  
   var oImg = "<img alt='' src='??????? + imgTextBin + "'>"; // What's the syntax here, please? 
   var x = document.getElementById(destinationDiv);
   x.innerHTML = oImg;  
}
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if the browser doesnt support data urls , you cant do what  you want. period , you'll have to use server side scripts( in php for instance ) to generate the image and the src of the img element should point to the server side script. But you can just append binary code to an element and hope it works ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question your are wanting to store images so you do not have to connect back with the server.  One way of doing this is to preload the images like `var img=new Image; img.src='path';` You could load all of the images into an array and you could then add them to the page as necessary.  There is a lot out there on image preloading since that seems what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already heard of the preload method, but it's queer to realize that there seems to be no syntax to declare a simple binary string as an image, since the browser itself is forcibly doing that exactly, so why HTML/Javascript would not allow the programmer any access to that function which must surely be found inside the browser's engine? It seems to me hard to believe!

Comment: @user1238012: There are many APIs where internal methods are wrapped in a pretty handler and not accessed directly. The browser's pretty handler is `Image()` and `<img>`.

Comment: thanks, I know that, but when I tried the method that I found in several parts of the web, doing: